# ReactJS + Redux force reducers to have state in same object-tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

i'm actually working on a ReactJS-Project in combination with Redux. 
I did some tests with submitted actions in some different reducers which are combined.

My Problem is that it seems that the reducer only edit its own "scope" inside of my application state. So if i got 2 reducers "ReducerA" and "ReducerB" with some states in it my State tree becomes this:

{

ReducerA:{
stateA: 2
},

ReducerB:{
stateA: 1
}

}

I'll build a initialize reducer which should be able to set information in ReducerA and even in ReducerB. Is that agains the FLUX / REDUX architecture?

Kind regards,
jDoe ;)

Comment: Import actions provided from reducers (A and B), and set Data to actions from your Component state or whatever for each actions of reducers, then dispatch it  to the store via connection to redux

Comment: So is it fully recommended/a best practice to make a initialize-call to the API and then "throw" all these datas through different actions to fill it in the right state ?